# Tangents and Exponential Curves

Tags: calculus

How do you find the gradient of a line given that it is a tangent to a curve? For example, if $y = mx$ is a tangent to the curve $y = e^{2x}$, how do I find $m$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at the same time that: $y = mx = e^{2x}$, and $m = 2e^{2x}$. Thus: $2xe^{2x} = e^{2x} \to x = 1/2$. So $m = 2e$.

Answer (score 0):

At $(x_0,e^{2x_0})$, the tangent line is $y = 2e^{2x_0}(x-x_0)+e^{2x_0}$. If it agrees with $y=mx$, we have $x_0=\frac{1}{2}$ since it passes through origin. Then you can find $m$.

Answer (score 0):

First differentiate $y=e^{2x} \\ y'=2e^{2x}$.

Then at some $x=k$, the gradient of the curve is $2e^{2k}$.

Now, if this tangent line is $y=mx$, then it must pass through the origin.

Find the equation of the tangent; Use this and the fact that it must pass through the origin to find $k$.

> $y-y_1=m(x-x_1) \\ y-e^{2k}=2e^{2k}(x-k)$.